# Creating a loop for a dataframe update the appends a series based on 2 variaables

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

Dataframe Shifts_to_Update has been developed to provide a list of call times and quantity of each call time that will be used to update the All_Shifts dataframe. These shifts will change from "busser" to "server" in the "Position" column in the All_Shifts table.

In this example, one 6:30 shift and one 10:00 shift need to become server positions.

```
Shifts_to_Update
  Call Time  quantity_shifts
0  06:30:00               2
1  10:00:00               1
```

The All_Shifts table needs to be updated accordingly.

```
All_Shifts
  myindex    Call Time  Position
0  1         06:30:00    busser
1  2         06:30:00    busser
2  3         06:30:00    busser
3  4         06:30:00    server 
4  5         07:00:00    busser
5  6         08:00:00    server
6  7         10:00:00    busser
7  8         10:00:00    busser
```

I created these lines that identify the "myindex" number for the shifts that need to be updated. These are the lines of codes I need help turning into a loop. I don't want to update .iloc[0] to .iloc[1] and so on for all the data I need to process.

```
o = Shifts_to_Update['Call Time'].iloc[0]
p = Shifts_to_Update['minimum_shifts'].iloc[0]
q = All_shifts[All_shifts['Call Time'] == o].head(p)
r = q[['r']]
```

r will return the "myindex" numbers that need to be update, the first and second rows with a 6:30 call time

```
myindexB
0        1
1        2
```

And then this line will make the update:

```
All_shifts.loc[All_shifts['myindex'].isin(r.index), "Position"] = "server"
```

So the final results looks like this:

```
All_Shifts
  myindex    Call Time  Position
0  1         06:30:00    server
1  2         06:30:00    server
2  3         06:30:00    busser
3  4         06:30:00    server 
4  5         07:00:00    busser
5  6         08:00:00    server
6  7         10:00:00    busser
7  8         10:00:00    busser
```

Please provide what type of loop can do this with 2 variables, iterating through the Shifts_to_Update table and appending to r. I want the final result to update the 6:30 and 10:00 positions in one run so the final output will look like this:

```
All_Shifts
      myindex    Call Time  Position
    0  1         06:30:00    server
    1  2         06:30:00    server
    2  3         06:30:00    busser
    3  4         06:30:00    server 
    4  5         07:00:00    busser
    5  6         08:00:00    server
    6  7         10:00:00    server
    7  8         10:00:00    busser
```